# Form não respeita Location definida manualmente

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu tenho este código para abrir um *form* que tem o tamanho 324x172.

Estou fazendo desta forma para abrir conforme a resolução:

```
FormLembreteCheque aviso = new FormLembreteCheque();
int c = Screen.PrimaryScreen.BitsPerPixel;
int w = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
int h = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;

switch (w)
{
    case 800:
        switch (h)
        {
            case 600:
                aviso.Location = new Point(476, 428);
                break;
        }
        break;

    case 1024:
        switch (h)
        {
            case 768:
                aviso.Location = new Point(700, 596);
                break;
        }
        break;

    case 1366:
        switch (h)
        {
            case 768:
                aviso.Location = new Point(1042, 596);
                break;
        }
        break;

    case 1440:
        switch (h)
        {
            case 900:
                aviso.Location = new Point(1116, 728);
                break;
            case 1050:
                aviso.Location = new Point(1116, 878);
                break;
        }
        break;
}
```

Porém cada hora ele abre em um local. Ele não segue a regra.

**EDIT**

Só para ajudar, quem for fazer e não quiser fazer `case`, para otimizar o código, eu fiz dessa forma:

```
aviso.Location = new Point((w - 324),(h - 200));
```

Comment: Seja mais específica. O que é `aviso`?

Comment: @LINQ n havia sido selecionado e ficou faltando, é o form, já editei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta "avisar" que você está setando a posição manualmente.

```
aviso.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado, até editei com uma otimização do código.